# Neo4j error when importing json file via Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, bloodhound

I am trying to import a Bloodhound/SharpHound json file into Neo4j but I am running into the following error:

`{
  "Neo4j only supports a subset of Cypher types for storage as singleton or array properties. Please refer to section cypher/syntax/values of the manual for more details.": 1
}`

This is my script:

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate('
call apoc.load.json("file:///sessions/20190822113758_groups.json") yield value
','
create (n:Groups) SET n += value
',{batchSize:10000})
```

this is what is in the json file:

```
{"domains":[{"Properties":{"objectsid":"S-1-2-2515432156546548","highvalue":true,"domain":"somethingone.COM"},"Name":"somethingone.COM","Links":null,"Trusts":[{"TargetName":"some.somethingtwo.COM","IsTransitive":true,"TrustDirection":2,"TrustType":"External"},{"TargetName":"something-three.COM","IsTransitive":true,"TrustDirection":2,"TrustType":"ParentChild"},{"TargetName":"somethingfour.COM","IsTransitive":true,"TrustDirection":0,"TrustType":"External"}],"Aces":null,"ChildOus":null,"Computers":null,"Users":null}],"meta":{"count":1,"type":"domains"}}
```

Comment: The error says, the value in your JSON in not of supported types. Can you share the sample JSON?

Comment: I added the contents of the json file above @Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo doesn't support properties on nodes being maps, or arrays of maps. For example, neither of the following work:

```
CREATE (n: Group) SET n.prop = { key: "value" }

Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof
```

```
CREATE (n: Group) SET n.prop = [{ key: "value" }, { key: "value" }]

Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Neo4j only supports a subset of Cypher types for storage as singleton or array properties. Please refer to section cypher/syntax/values of the manual for more details.
```

The second is the error you're seeing, but they're basically equivalent - you're trying to add a property to a node with an unsupported data type. If you look at your JSON file, the `domains` map is itself an array of maps which themselves contain further maps...

[image]

You will need to think about what the graph structure is that you want to generate from the JSON file, and then instead of just `CREATE (n: Group) n += value` you'll probably need to `UNWIND` the `value.domains` array and create the nodes and properties by traversing the nested maps that represent the JSON.

For example, the following would create Group nodes with a 'Name' property, and Trust nodes with the information from the `Trusts` array:

```
call apoc.load.json("file:///sessions/20190822113758_groups.json") yield value
UNWIND value.domains as domain
MERGE (g: Group { Name: domain.Name })
WITH g, domain.Trusts as trusts
UNWIND trusts as trust
MERGE (t: Trust { TrustType: trust.TrustType, TrustDirection: trust.TrustDirection, TargetName: trust.TargetName, IsTransitive: trust.IsTransitive })
MERGE (t)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(g)
RETURN t, g
```

You may find you need to make multiple calls to `apoc.load.json` and create the graph in parts - maybe first creating Groups, then Trusts, then Properties and so on joining the nodes up as you go, it's hard to tell with all the `nulls` in the example JSON file.